# Download file with DataLakeFileClient and progress bar

Tags: download, progress-bar, chunks, tqdm, azure-data-lake-gen2

I need to download a large file from Azure with DataLakeFileClient and show a progress bar like tqdm during the download. Below is the code that I was trying with a smaller test file.

```
# Download a File
test_file = DataLakeFileClient.from_connection_string(my_conn_str, file_system_name=fs_name, file_path="161263.tmp")

download = test_file.download_file()
blocks = download.chunks()
print(f"File Size = {download.size}, Number of blocks = {len(blocks)}")

with open("./newfile.tmp", "wb") as my_file:
    for block in tqdm(blocks):
        my_file.write(block)
```

Results show like below in jupyter notebook, with number of blocks the same as file size.
[image: File Size = 2673252, Number of blocks = 2673252]

How can I make the number of blocks correct and the progress bar work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using chucks, you should note that only the file size is larger than `32MB`(`33554432 bytes`), then the file size(here, the file size means that `total file size - 32MB`) will be split into blocks with `4MB` size for each block.

For example, if the file size is 39MB, it will be split into 3 blocks. The first block is 32MB, the 2nd block is 4MB, the 3rd block is 3MB(`39MB - 32MB - 4MB`).

Here is an example, it can work well at my side:

```
from tqdm import tqdm
from azure.storage.filedatalake import DataLakeFileClient
import math

conn_str = "xxxxxxxx"
file_system_name="xxxx"
file_name="ccc.txt"

test_file = DataLakeFileClient.from_connection_string(conn_str,file_system_name,file_name)

download = test_file.download_file()

blocks = download.chunks()

number_of_blocks = 0

#if the file size is larger than 32MB
if len(blocks) > 33554432:
    number_of_blocks = math.ceil((len(blocks) - 33554432) / 1024 / 1024 / 4) + 1
else:
    number_of_blocks = 1
    
print(f"File Size = {download.size}, Number of blocks = {number_of_blocks}")

#initialize a tqdm instance
progress_bar = tqdm(total=download.size,unit='iB',unit_scale=True)

with open("D:\\a11\\ccc.txt","wb") as my_file:
    for block in blocks:
        #update the progress bar
        progress_bar.update(len(block))

        my_file.write(block)

progress_bar.close()

print("**completed**")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is exactly what I was looking for.