# how to use lxml iterparse from Azure StorageStreamDownloader?

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage, lxml

I'm currently using `lxml.etree.iterparse` to iterate over an XML file tag by tag. Locally this works fine but I want to move the XML file to an Azure Blob Storage and process the file in an Azure function. However, I'm a bit stuck on trying to parse the XML file from the `StorageStreamDownloader`

**Code locally**

```
from lxml import etree

context = etree.iterparse('c:\\Users\\', tag='InstanceElement')

for event, elem in context:
    # processing of the tag
```

**Streaming from Blob**

```
from lxml import etree
from azure.storage.filedatalake import DataLakeServiceClient

connect_str = ''
service = DataLakeServiceClient.from_connection_string(conn_str=connect_string)

System = service.get_file_system_client('')
FileClient = System.get_file_client('')
Stream = FileClient.download_file()

# Stuck on what the input must be for iterparse
context = etree.iterparse(, tag='InstanceElement')

for event, elem in context:
    # processing of the tag
```

I'm stuck at what the input of `iterparse` must be, so any ideas on how to parse the XML file while streaming it?

Comment: Yes thanks for your solution, only question that remains is how this relates to memory usage in an Azure function because won't the readall() method read the entire file into memory?

Comment: Yes, it will load the entire file, if your file size is less than 1.5G, it is ok.If your file is too large to load, you can download this file by chunk:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66145017/download-file-with-datalakefileclient-and-progress-bar  to function and remove it after use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
from lxml import etree
from azure.storage.filedatalake import DataLakeServiceClient
from io  import BytesIO

connect_str = ''
service = DataLakeServiceClient.from_connection_string(conn_str=connect_str)

System = service.get_file_system_client('')
FileClient = System.get_file_client('test.xml')
content = FileClient.download_file().readall()

context = etree.iterparse(BytesIO(content), tag='InstanceElement')
for event, elem in context:
    print(elem.text)
```

Content of my `test.xml`:

[image]

Result:

[image]